# Is it possible to scroll to any part of HTML document using only link to it?

Tags: html, hyperlink

So I want to use link like http://example.com/fo.html#line22 on ANY HTML page (meaning I can not change the page HTML code but I can read it before giving link) to scroll to line 22 of HTML document or knowing contents to some Known as existing line or button on that page.
How to do such thing?

Comment: What does `line22` represent here? The 22th line of the *source code* or the *displayed output*? If the latter, how would you distinguish lines precisely? Paragraphs? Linebreaks? Wrapped lines?

Comment: The 22th line of the displayed output

Comment: jak: are you aware that the 22nd line on your display might be vastly different than the 22nd line on my display? And how do you define a "line"? What if the page is all images for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you are going to be able to do this by just editing the link if you don't have a named anchor, as stated a couple times before in this thread, but...

If you can read the document you can also substitute it.

- read and cache the document, placing a tiny snip of html where you want to scroll to like this:

  `<span id="scroll-to-id"><!-- nothing in here --></span>`
- instead of the original url, give a link to your cached page with the id of your inserted snippet:

  `http://www.yourwebsite.com/scrollto.php?{urlencoded-url-of-other-page}?scrollto={linenumber};#scroll-to-id`

scrollto.php should fetch the html document, process and cache it according to linenumber.

You'll probably also want to insert a header into the cache stating you don't own the page and add a link to the page in its original context.

You'll still have to work out what constitutes a line to find the right place in the document, but you could probably load the external html into a [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/domdocument), convert to text (`$document->documentElement->nodeValue` should get you started) and work with that.

Answer (score 5):

No, a named anchor or other element would need to be present on the page with the same `id` or `name` as supplied in the hash value of the url.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Examples

[RFC 5147](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5417) proposes something similar for plain text documents only. However, none of the mainstream browsers have implemented this functionality yet.

> RFC 5147 proposes a fragment identifier for **text/plain** [read: not HTML] documents, based on character and line positions and ranges within the document using the keywords "char" and "line".[6] This example identifies lines 11 through 20 of a text document, for instance:
>
> - http://example.com/document.txt#line=10,20

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URl to link to any element with an ID or name attribute, but **there's nothing else you can do to direct the browser** unless you control the source.

IDs are usually found in many places on the page, so by reading through the source you might find something to grab onto. For example, you could link to http://example.com/fo.html#login_box to make the page scroll down to the login box below.

```
<div id="login_box">
   Username:
   Password:
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be hard and painful. I'd recommend to just scroll by pixels with help of [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.scrollTo).

```
window.onload = function() {
    var line = parseInt(location.hash.replace(/#line/, ''));
    if (line) window.scrollTo(0, 10 * line);
};
```

This way `page#line22` will scroll down by 220 pixels. You can modify the pixels-per-line in the code (which is currently `10`).

Comment: He's wanting to do it for any page, though - pages not under his own control.  It's almost not even programming related.

Comment: You're right. I forgot the "not under control" part. Maybe an iframe will help. Or just homegrowing some server side proxy which alters the source to add `<a name="linenumber">` to every line prior to display.